# MySQL - sort 2 columns by joining to one

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a question.

I am working on a SQL query which will join 2 columns in one table to one column and will sort the result in ascending order (by that column).

So, lets imagine we have a table with auto-incement *IDs*. In same table we have column *parentID* (can be 0 or reffering to an existing ID).

```
ID | parentID | column1 | column2 | number
-------------------------------------------
1  | 0        | data    | data   | 1
2  | 0        | data    | data   | 1
3  | 1        | data    | data   | 1
4  | 2        | data    | data   | 1
5  | 0        | data    | data   | 1
6  | 4        | data    | data   | 1
7  | 1        | data    | data   | 1
```

And I want to get result where *ID* and *parentID* will be joined and sorted together. So the table will look like. (if *parentID* will be 0, sort it by *ID*)

```
ID | parentID | JOINEDCOLUMN | column1 | column2 | number
-------------------------------------------
1  | 0        | 1              | data    | data   | 1
3  | 1        | 1              | data    | data   | 1
7  | 1        | 1              | data    | data   | 1
2  | 0        | 2              | data    | data   | 1
4  | 2        | 2              | data    | data   | 1
6  | 4        | 4              | data    | data   | 1
5  | 0        | 5              | data    | data   | 1
```

(I do not want data from JOINED COLUMN, but the sorted table as result -> PHP...)

I have a query - which is not working as expected -> returning parentID rows twice if they are not 0.

```
SELECT 
   id as JOINEDCOLUMN, parentID, column1, column2, column3 
FROM table 
WHERE number = 1 
UNION 
SELECT 
   parentID, parentID, column1, column2, column3 
FROM table 
WHERE number = 1 AND parentID <> 0
ORDER BY `JOINEDCOLUMN` ASC
```

Comment: what you mean by JOINEDCOLUMN can you explain it more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` in your `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  demo  /* add your filter WHERE number = 1 */
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN parentID = 0 
    THEN ID 
    ELSE parentID 
  END
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46ad37/2), [Select](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46ad37/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life. :) Thank for the demo too. :) I have never used `CASE`, so i didn`t know, that it exists.